# Ajax to ColdFusion Remote .cfc returns 404 on different server

Tags: ajax, coldfusion

I've got the following method in my cfc file:

```
<cffunction name="handleForm" returnType="string" access="remote" returnFormat="JSON">
```

I do the following call via jQuery/Javascript:

```
$.post($(this).attr('action'), {
            formData: form
        }, function(data){ //Other stuff
```

I was to stress this. **Everything above works on my dev server.** When I move my entire file set to production this call returns a 404. When I navigate to the /url/page.cfc?method=handleForm in my browser on dev I get an error stating the required argument is missing, when I do it on prod... 404.

I've looked at my IIS settings, etc, but I can't figure out why the 404. We have many other applications on prod that do exactly this and it works fine, but this new application I am building is doing this. What could cause this and how do I troubleshoot it. It makes no sense. Both servers have the same setup, same files, same everything as far as I can tell.

Comment: There a number of reasons for this. Start with your extension mapping in IIS to make sure .cfc is mapped to ColdFusion just like CFM's are. Check that CFM's actually do work, that it's not a larger issue. Look for URL rewrites and security settings in IIS. Also check your IIS logs for some hints.

Comment: extension mapping you mean mime types. Never mind, I see it in handler mappings.

Comment: I have the same rewrite rules in prod/dev. cfms work because the entire site works and is all ColdFusion. .cfc is cfcHandler and cfm is cfmHandler.

Comment: Set `errorMode` to `Detailed` in your `web.config` (i.e. turn on detailed errors in the IIS GUI) and check where the requested URL points to.

Comment: Did that and it just gives the 404 no more detail.

Comment: Ah. Had to change it to Auto instead of Pass Through. I "think" I found it. The physical path & requested URL is appending .cfm onto the .cfc.

Comment: Do you have any rewrites rules? Mind to share the `web.config` with us?

Comment: It's got to be one of my rules, which I'm looking at this morning, but it doesn't explain why the same rules work on dev but fail on prod. After I take a look see I'll report back, possibly with another question.

Comment: So it was a waterfall. Every new site you add in IIS you have to add a Virtural jakarta directory that is the path to the isapi_redirect.dll. Because I didn't add it, pages outside the root are missing and the rewrite rule appended the .cfm which confused me. I didn't notice because all of my "pages" are a single page with stuff pulled in. One of those things I forgot to do when setting up the new site.

Comment: If you want to avoid the Jakarta mapping, then you could use the boncode handler with CF instead. http://www.michaels.me.uk/post.cfm/running-railo-and-coldfusion-10-side-by-side-with-boncode